# Error with RecyclerView in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am writing an android app which utilizes a custom adapter I made using RecyclerView.  The adapter works fine however when I navigate away from the activity which is utilizing it, the app crashes and gives me this error:

```
07-22 14:30:41.037 11083-11083/com.epicodus.parkr E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: com.epicodus.parkr, PID: 11083
                                                                java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$SavedState
                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onSaveInstanceState(RecyclerView.java:1078)
                                                                    at android.view.View.dispatchSaveInstanceState(View.java:14641)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchFreezeSelfOnly(ViewGroup.java:3175)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchSaveInstanceState(RecyclerView.java:1109)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3161)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3161)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3161)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3161)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3161)
                                                                    at android.view.View.saveHierarchyState(View.java:14624)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.saveHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:2126)
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1456)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:564)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onSaveInstanceState(AppCompatActivity.java:502)
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1383)
                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1286)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.callCallActivityOnSaveInstanceState(ActivityThread.java:4473)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3845)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3908)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Here is the code for the activity which utilizes the adapter:

```
package com.epicodus.parkr.ui;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.epicodus.parkr.Constants;
import com.epicodus.parkr.R;
import com.epicodus.parkr.adapters.RentedSpotsAdapter;
import com.epicodus.parkr.models.Spot;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class AccountActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private String uid;
private DatabaseReference mSpecificUserReference;
private DatabaseReference mAllSpotsReference;
private RentedSpotsAdapter mAdapter;


@Bind(R.id.rentedSpotRecyclerView) RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
@Bind(R.id.userNameDisplay) TextView mUserNameDisplay;
@Bind(R.id.headline) TextView mHeadline;
@Bind(R.id.logOutButton) Button mLogOutButton;
@Bind(R.id.postSpotButton) Button mPostSpotButton;
@Bind(R.id.findSpotsButton) Button mFindSpotsButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    uid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    mSpecificUserReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Constants.FIREBASE_CHILD_USER).child(uid);
    mAllSpotsReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("spots");


    mSpecificUserReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String userName = dataSnapshot.child("fullName").getValue().toString();
             mUserNameDisplay.setText(userName);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    mSpecificUserReference.child("rentedSpots").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        ArrayList<Spot> mSpots = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> spotKeys = new ArrayList<>();
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot spotKeySnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String spotKey = spotKeySnapshot.getValue().toString();
                spotKeys.add(spotKey);
            }
            mAllSpotsReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot AllSpotsDataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot eachSpotSnapshot : AllSpotsDataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        String compareSpotId = eachSpotSnapshot.getKey();
                        for(String eachSpotKey : spotKeys)
                            if(compareSpotId.equals(eachSpotKey)){
                                String ownerId = eachSpotSnapshot.child("ownerID").getValue().toString();
                                String address = eachSpotSnapshot.child("address").getValue().toString();
                                String description = eachSpotSnapshot.child("description").getValue().toString();
                                Double lat = Double.parseDouble(eachSpotSnapshot.child("latLng").child("latitude").getValue().toString());
                                Double lng = Double.parseDouble(eachSpotSnapshot.child("latLng").child("longitude").getValue().toString());
                                LatLng newLatLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                                String startDate = eachSpotSnapshot.child("startDate").getValue().toString();
                                String startTime = eachSpotSnapshot.child("startTime").getValue().toString();
                                String endDate = eachSpotSnapshot.child("endDate").getValue().toString();
                                String endTime = eachSpotSnapshot.child("endTime").getValue().toString();
                                Spot newSpot = new Spot(eachSpotKey, ownerId, address, description, newLatLng, startDate, startTime, endDate, endTime);
                                mSpots.add(newSpot);
                            }
                    }
                    mAdapter = new RentedSpotsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mSpots);
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(AccountActivity.this);
                    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    finish();
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            finish();
        }
    });


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_account);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    Typeface newFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Lobster-Regular.ttf");
    mHeadline.setTypeface(newFont);

    Intent infoIntent = getIntent();
    String userName = infoIntent.getStringExtra("user");
    mUserNameDisplay.setText(userName);

    mPostSpotButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mLogOutButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mFindSpotsButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void logout() {
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
    Intent intent = new Intent(AccountActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view == mLogOutButton){
        logout();
    } else if (view == mPostSpotButton){
        Intent postSpotIntent = new Intent (AccountActivity.this, NewSpotActivity.class);
        startActivity(postSpotIntent);
    } else if (view == mFindSpotsButton){
        Intent findSpotsIntent = new Intent(AccountActivity.this, FindSpotsActivity.class);
        startActivity(findSpotsIntent);
    }
}
}
```

And here is the code for the Adapter itself:

```
package com.epicodus.parkr.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.epicodus.parkr.R;
import com.epicodus.parkr.models.Spot;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;


public class RentedSpotsAdapter extends    RecyclerView.Adapter<RentedSpotsAdapter.RentedSpotViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<Spot> mSpots;
private Context mContext;

public RentedSpotsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Spot> spots){
    mSpots = spots;
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public RentedSpotsAdapter.RentedSpotViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rented_spot_list_item, parent, false);
    RentedSpotViewHolder viewHolder = new RentedSpotViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RentedSpotsAdapter.RentedSpotViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bindSpot(mSpots.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mSpots.size();
}

public class RentedSpotViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @Bind(R.id.rentedSpotAddressDisplay) TextView mRentedSpotAddressDisplay;
    @Bind(R.id.rentedSpotEndDateDisplay) TextView mRentedSpotEndDateDisplay;
    @Bind(R.id.rentedSpotEndTimeDisplay) TextView mRentedSpotEndTimeDisplay;

    private Context mContext;

    public RentedSpotViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        mContext = itemView.getContext();
    }

    public void bindSpot(Spot spot){
        mRentedSpotAddressDisplay.setText(spot.getAddress());
        mRentedSpotEndDateDisplay.setText(spot.getEndDate());
        mRentedSpotEndTimeDisplay.setText(spot.getEndTime());
    }
}
}
```

Here is the app level build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.epicodus.parkr"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.2'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'

compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.0.2'
}

 configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy {
    force 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    force 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Update**

I got it working.  It looks like I just had to override the onSaveInstanceState method and have it be empty.

Comment: So this java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$SavedState seems to point to something

Comment: Please add your build.gradle where you have the recyclerview dependency

Comment: Added the build.gradle file in the main post

Comment: How about override `onSaveInstanceState(outState)` in activity with a blank function(not call `super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)`) if the app don't need support both landscape and portrait mode.

Comment: Thanks sakiM that did the trick!

Comment: Or you can remove line
force 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
from block
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy {
    force 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    force 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
}
It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Just guessing here.. Can you move the code and place it immediately after oncreate() method and try again.

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_account);

Comment: Do you mean outside of the onCreate method? Cause it wont work if its not inside onCreate

Comment: Inside the onCreate() method